# Python count numbers from input file

Tags: python, file, count

I want to write a Python 3 script to read in an input file, like this:

```
8 13 67 43 47
9 19 5 3 69
93 21 25 53 20
```

and then count how many numbers are in the file and find the max. I wrote the following script:

```
file = open ("input.dat","r")
count = 0
for line in file :
   parts = line.split()
   count +=1
   print (count)
```

But it only counts the number of lines. How do I count the number of numbers? In the file?

Comment: You want to count all numbers? If it's so, try to replace count += 1 to count += len(parts), and move print(count) out of for loop

Comment: You said you don't want to use lists although you are using one yourself: line.split()

Comment: MihanEntalpo yes that works for the count!! how can i total them and find the max?

Comment: Are all numbers separated by a single space?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you do not want to use lists. However, split() method acts on a string and converts it to a list. I'd focus my answer on the two requirements you specifically mentioned. If there are other requirements, please mention them in the comments below.

**Counting the numbers**

To do this, you can simply read each line, use split to break it into a list of numbers, and then add the length of that string to a running total.

Here's the code for the same:

```
file = open ("input.dat","r")
total_numbers = 0
for line in file :
   parts = line.split()
   total_numbers += len(parts)
print (total_numbers)
```

**Finding the maximum number**

As for finding the maximum number is present, for each line you can find the maximum number using inbuilt `max` function and select the maximum number out of the maximum numbers for each line.

This is how it can be achieved.

```
file = open ("input.dat","r")
total_numbers = 0
# Storing the most minimum number possible inside max_num
# '-inf' is a special string which implies tending to negative infinity
max_num = float('-inf')
for line in file :
   parts = line.split()
   # split() stores the numbers as a string inside the list
   # map() converts the list of strings into a list of integers
   parts = map(int, parts)
   max_num_in_line = max(parts)
   # If the maximum number in the line being read is more than max_num, replace max_num by that number
   if max_num_in_line > max_num:
      max_num = max_num_in_line
print (max_num)
```

I hope this helps. Do let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you want easily using lists:

```
with open ("input.dat","r") as file:
    data = file.read()

#Extract all integers in the file into 1 list
list_of_integers = [int(i) for i in x.replace('\n',' ').split()] 

#Now you can whatever you please
count(list_of_integers)
max(list_of_integers)
sum(list_of_integers)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `list` in your solution you can try this to calculate maximum number and count of all numbers

```
file = open ("input.dat","r")
count = 0
max = 0
for line in file :
   #Reading file will result in list of numbers like ['1', '2', '3'], so you have to map them to int
   parts = list(map(int, line.split()))
   #Count of all numbers in a line
   count = count + len(parts)
   #Max number in a lint
   max_iter = max(parts)
   #Update max if previous max was smaller
   if max_iter > max:
      max = max_iter
print ("Total Numbers: {}, Maximum Number: {}".format(count,max))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

digit_count=0
number_count = 0
numbers = []
count=0

with open ("letters_and_numbers.txt") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    sub_strs = line.rstrip().split("-")
    for i in range(0, len(sub_strs)):
      file_words = re.split(r"[a-zA-Z\W]",sub_strs[i])
      for word in file_words:
        if word.isdigit():
          digit_count += len(word)
          number_count += 1
          if i >=1 and sub_strs[i].startswith(word):
            count-=int(word)
            digit_count+=1
            numbers.append("-")
            numbers.append(word)
          else:
            count+=int(word)
            numbers.append(word)

print "digits:",digit_count
print "amount of numbers:",number_count
print "numbers:",numbers
print "total:",count
```

This code counts the numbers in a file even if the file looks like this:

gfwgf8943758834y34ty3yttubf37t73

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open ("input.dat","r")
sum = 0
for line in file :
   parts = line.split()
   sum+=len(parts)
   # Print the total number in a line
   print (sum)
   parts = map(int, parts)
   max_in_line = max(parts)
   if(max<max_in_line)
       max = max_in_line
print(sum)
print(max)
```